# How to print key and value of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. Is it possible to print key values using array.map method?

```
<div> +
array.map( x => {
return `<span class="key">"value"</span><br>
}) +
</div>
```

Comment: Why not using **entries()**, **keys()** & **values()**?

Comment: Do you mean every key and every value of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
const array = [{
  key: '1',
  value: 'value-1'
}, {
  key: '2',
  value: 'value-2'
}];
const text = array.map(x => `<span class="${x.key}">${x.value}</span><br>`).join("");
const element = document.querySelector('#log');
element.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: wdym by "If your objects have key and value"? Doesn't objects have key value bu default?

Comment: Objects can be empty, can have only key, whatever. Or I don't get the question right.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini if you want to iterate through the object, like through the dictionary, then `Object.entries` should be the right choice

Comment: Yea I think you misunderstood it. He has definitely entries. Despite I told him, he can use **entries**, **keys** & **values**.

Comment: Ill check tomorrow, in case- will delete the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping through `Object.keys()` of every object in the array this way

```
<div>
  array.map( obj => {
    return obj.keys().map( key => {
      return `<span class="${key}">${obj[key]}</span><br>`
    )}
  })
</div>
```